# how to preserve interface language for a multilingual website?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I have a multilingual website with five different languages represented. I have to manage and maintain all the languages, but each time I switch to a particular translation for a piece of content the interface changes too.

I speak English - how do I maintain the interface language in English while managing the translated content?

This too is true for coworkers - the native Japanese speaker needs to be able to maintain the Japanese while he works.

The language preferences for each user is set to their native language - is there a way to have that enforce the interface language we are working in when administering the site?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet might be the [Administration Language](http://drupal.org/project/admin_language) module. It allows you to set the general and user specific administration language. The module doesn't seem to be maintained currently/anymore though and there's only a dev version for the Drupal 7.x branch so you may want to check the bug reports and test it first. I've used it on a few sites without running into any major issues so it should be worth a shot still.

Answer (score 1):

I might be mistaken, but I think if you set your default language editing your own user, it will be preserved when editing content on localized versions of the site.